# while loop sp_executeSQL - incorrect syntax near @parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've inherited a monster stored procedure & noticed that some parts of the stored procedure were concatenating values into a SQL string during a WHILE loop. After looking at ways to optimize it I found you can use Dynamic SQL strings via parameterization. I've done my best stab at it below.

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @iter INT;

SET @iter = 2;
SET @ParamDefinition = N'@iter tinyint'
SET @SQLString = 
                 N'with ctex as 
                               (
                                    select *,
                                            sum(turnover) over (partition by wfd_mpl_id, out_id, variant,
                                                                order by month rows between @iter-1 preceding and current row) as calcfulfilrollingbalance 
                                    from #exploded
                                    where fulfilcm = @iter
                               )

                               update ctex set fulfilrollingbalance = calcfulfilrollingbalance
                               where fulfilcm = @iter;'

WHILE (@iter<36)
BEGIN
    PRINT @SQLString
    EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @iter=@iter
    SET @iter = @iter +1
END;
```

Despite not seeing any obvious errors with the query I'm getting the error `Incorrect syntax near @iter`

I used `PRINT @SQLString` to trouble shoot the string however I still see `@iter` within the string. I'm not sure I'm doing things correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: The length of @SQLString is too small and your query string is getting truncated.

Comment: The window boundary must be a literal… ‘rows between @iter-1 preceding’ will give an error @ iter.. it should be ‘rows between 3 preceding’ when for eg. @ iter=4 … which requires string concatenation/manipulation for the dynamic sql approach

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. When I get back into work I'll have another look. One question lptr for the window boundary could I create a separate parameter that's always 1 value behind @iter?